# Xcode open a youtube video after tap on dynamic content

Tags: ios, xcode, video, youtube

I want to open youtube videos after the user hits an image, that is generated dynamically. The user searches for a videos, and it appears 10 images previews on the scree (that part is done), know I want to detect the tap on that views and open a youtube video that correspond to that preview.

Do you know how I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: so whats your need exactly ? how to play you tube video ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tag of image followed by its url.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? :)

Comment: Since you are getting the image of video,you must be getting other infos too,and there may be some kind of URL within that info,that you can use to play it.